# Can I add an enchanted apple cooldown?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

Is there a way to add a cooldown for eating enchanted apples? I don't want the player to be able to eat a lot at once in my PVP game.

Answer (score -1):

There are a few ways you can achieve that effect but most of the ways I can think of are kind of ugly, but this one is probably the cleanest.

## Concept

Every few seconds, the player will get an enchanted golden apple. They will not be given one if they already have one.

## Commands

Place a *repeating always active* command block with the command:

```
clear @a appleenchanted -1 1
```

Then a *chain always active*:

```
give @a appleenchanted
```

Set the delay of the first command block to how many seconds the cooldown should be multiplied by 20 (i.e. 10 seconds = 200).